# Fetching rows with a certain enum status

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

I am trying to have a display (Completed Repairs = ?) on my admin dashboard that displays the number of laptop repairs completed based on the status column.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=MYAPP',
'MYUSERNAME',
'MYPASSWORD'
);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM repairs WHERE current_status > Repair Completed";

//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num'];
?>
```

But i am getting this error: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PATH_TO_PHP_FILE.php on line 208

Line 208 is:

```
echo $row['num'];
```

I am a complete newby so i have no idea what to do here.

I am using "num" cause i want to get the number of rows that have a status of "Repair Completed".

I have looked around on stackoverflow but i am not really understanding any of it.

What am i missing from my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax errors here `current_status > Repair Completed`. What is `Repair` and `Completed`?

Comment: Repair Completed is an ENUM value

Comment: I think you need to wrap it in quotes to make it a string literal. Or if this is a column name with a space then you need to wrap it in backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql request seems wrong so it returns false try

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM repairs WHERE current_status = 'Repair Completed'"
```

And after that do a var_dump of $row